# Concat all the text files and their content contained in all the .zip files in a text file using Python

Tags: python, file-io, readfile

I am trying to write a program that would read all files in a folder and output all of their contents into one single file. The files are ziped with the .gz extension. I managed to read one file but not all its contents and not the rest of the files. Here is my code:

```
import glob, gzip, re
import pickle

filed = open('Logs.txt', 'w')


logfilenames = glob.glob('*.gz')




logformat = re.compile(r'^\S+ \S+ \S+ \[([\w:/]+\s[+\-]\d{4})\] "(\S+) (\S+) .*" (\d+) (\d+) "([^"]*)" "[^"]*"')
with gzip.GzipFile(logfilenames[0],'r') as f:
    for i in glob.glob('*.gz'):
        txtline = f.readline()
        parsedline = logformat.match(txtline)
        print "time={t} size={s} url={u}".format(t=parsedline.group(1), s=parsedline.group(5), u=parsedline.group(3))

        pickle.dump(["time={t} size={s} url={u}".format(t=parsedline.group(1), s=parsedline.group(5), u=parsedline.group(3))],filed)

filed.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (didn't touch your regular expression):

```
import glob, gzip, re
import cPickle

logformat = re.compile(r'^\S+ \S+ \S+ \[([\w:/]+\s[+\-]\d{4})\] "(\S+) (\S+) .*" (\d+) (\d+) "([^"]*)" "[^"]*"')

with open('Logs.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for i in glob.glob('*.gz'):
        with gzip.GzipFile(i,'r') as f_in:
            for txtline in f_in:
                parsedline = logformat.match(txtline)
                if parsedline:
                    f_out.write("time={t} size={s} url={u}".format(t=parsedline.group(1), s=parsedline.group(5), u=parsedline.group(3)))
```

Comment: Thanks @eumiro it reads all files in the folder only problem now it only reads just one line from each file

Comment: It runs for a bit (reading files) then crashes mid way and gives me this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @AdamAdamou - please see my updated version checking for `if parsedline`, which should fix your `AttributeError`s. This means some lines are not matched by your regexp.

Answer (score 0):

save this as xD.sh

```
mkdir dir
mv $file dir
cd dir
tar -zxvf $file
for file in `ls -w 1 | grep -v ".gz"`; do
cat $file >> joint-file
done
mv joint-file ../
rm -rf dir
```

and then use it from python with

```
import os
cmd = './xd.sh'
os.system(cmd)
```

=)

Comment: OP wants apparently more than just `cat`. See his regular expressions.

Comment: My answer is 50% joke-ish. You can still use apply some regexps after unzipping it, just use your favourite combination of AWK, sed, etc.